# interactive matplotlib figure: show and then close an image on top of a graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am creating an interactive matplotlib figure. It is interactive in the sense that when I press a letter 'i' on the keyboard, an image is loaded into the figure. In a second step I would like to remove the image again, while I am still showing the plot. I really don't want to redraw the plot, as it takes too much time.

I am using `plt.imshow(img)` to display the image. So far I have not come across an equivalent that closes the image. I can only close the complete figure. Does anyone know of such a function?

Comment: Show us your code, and maybe we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

PLT is tricky. In general, plt.COMMANDS apply to the most recently created object and don't offer much control over the figure, axis, plots, etc. If you label your global plt variables, it makes it more clear.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = [1,2,3,4]
Y = [1,1,3,3.5]

figure = plt.figure()              #Creates the window. 
axis   = figure.add_subplot(1,1,1) #Creates a graphic inside the window. 
axis.grid(True)                    #Change the axis. 
plots  = axis.plot(X,Y)            #Put a plot in the axis. 

figure.show()                      #Open the window.
```

Note, that plots is a list, since arrays, X and Y, could have generated many plots. Now, lets delete the plot while the window is open and watch it disappear, then insert the plot back into the axis.

```
plots[0].remove()

plots  = axis.plot(X,Y)
```

In your case, you are working with axis.imshow() instead of axis.plot().